# Gravity Forms - Populate Fields with Data from Another Form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am using gravity forms to develop a hiring system on WordPress. One of the things we want to offer is easily filling out and submitting the standard HR paperwork (W4, I9, etc.).

Some of these forms have fields that are repeated on other documents, and over the multiple forms this can become a very tedious process of filling out information. Social Security Number is an easy example of this, but there are many others such as marital status, names, and addresses.

**I'd like to enable a user on the system to fill out the form for the I9, and then when they go to another form (such as the W4, Direct Deposit, a General Information form, etc.), the data they entered previously is prefilled in the document and they only have to fill in the blanks.**

I have seen this feature offered on a couple other systems such as ExactHire and Formatta, but I can't seem to find info on how to recreate the functionality. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, as I know this is a feature that can help a lot of form users. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to pre-populate the fields in a gravity form. The issue might be where is the data coming from. If they are logged in - this would be much easier. If they are not logged in, you'll have to store the information somewhere client-side -- like in a cookie -- but that might not be the most optimal solution.

If they are logged in, you can query other forms filled out by that user ID and fetch the information that way. Or when they fill out one of the forms for the first time, you can update user meta on their user that gives a place to store this default info. Then just fetch and use Gravity Forms hooks to pre-populate.

If they are not logged in, you can store the data in cookies or local storage - although there may be privacy issues around that. Its much more difficult to persist this info if they are not actually logged in.

See link below on how to use hooks to pre-populate gravity forms.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_value_parameter_name/

I can put a brief example together if that would be helpful.

---

**Edit 1:** An example was requested.

I'd start by identifying the type of data that is duplicated across the forms. Sounds like you have a good idea of that already.

Then, figure out how you want to store this data. Might make most sense to add additional fields via user_meta, since these people will be users. Maybe the users have a profile page, and they can pre-fill this basic info as a setup process and then use that? Maybe once they fill out their first form, you collect the data at that time and save it on their user. Maybe both! Alternatively, you could not store the info on the user, and just query other gravity forms filled out by this user and grab it that way, but that seems potentially inefficient, and messy since data isn't stored logically.

To save the form data to the user meta, you can start with the function below. Note this is very basic and should be improved (validation, conditional logic if values exist, etc).

**Note**: the hook 'gform_after_submission' will target all forms. You can specify the form ID this targets by adding the form ID at the end. Example for a form with the ID of 3 would be: 'gform_after_submission_3'

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'input_fields', 10, 2 );
function input_fields( $entry, $form ) {
    //this assumes 1 is the numerical ID of the gravity forms field.
    $marital_status = $entry[1];
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'marital_status', $marital_status );
    // others here
}
```

To grab the data and auto-fill the form, you'll have to have some functions similar to one below.

**Note**: you need to go edit the gravity form, edit the fields, and under 'advanced' select 'Allow field to be populated dynamically' - and give it a name. That name is used below as a suffix on the filter name. For example: gform_field_value_NAME_YOU_GAVE_IT. Below I used 'marital_status' as my field name.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_marital_status', 'populate_marital_status' );
function populate_marital_status( $value ) {
   $maritalStatus = get_user_meta( wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'marital_status', true );
   return $maritalStatus;
}
```

- Dealing with user meta:
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta
- Controlling form values BEFORE it loads:
  https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_value_parameter_name/
- Getting data from gravity forms AFTER submission:
  https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/

Comment: Hey Marcus, thank you very much! The users would definitely be logged in. 

If it's not too much trouble, an example would be great!

Comment: Updated with example!